# Tar only the Directory structure

Tags: unix, tar

I want to copy my directory structure excluding the files. Is there any option in the tar to ignore all files and copy only the Directories recursively.

Answer (score 19):

You can use find to get the directories and then tar them:

```
find .. -type d -print0 | xargs -0 tar cf dirstructure.tar --no-recursion
```

If you have more than about 10000 directories use the following to work around xargs limits:

```
find . -type d -print0 | tar cf dirstructure.tar --no-recursion --null --files-from -
```

Comment: In earlier GNU tars apparently the position where you placed the **--no-recursion** argument did not matter for it to work while in more current versions it apparently needs to preceed the **--files-from** option... My backups just exploded after upgrading from Debian Wheezy to Debian Stretch which includes GNU tar 1.29. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I've edited the answer and moved `--no-recursion` before `--files-from`.

Answer (score 6):

Directory names that contain spaces or other special characters may require extra attention.  For example:

```
$ mkdir -p "backup/My Documents/stuff"
$ find backup/ -type d | xargs tar cf directory-structure.tar --no-recursion
tar: backup/My: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Documents: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: backup/My: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Documents/stuff: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Here are some variations to handle these cases of "unusual" directory names:

```
$ find backup/ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 tar cf directory-structure.tar --no-recursion
```

Using *-print0* with find will emit filenames as null-terminated strings; with *-0* xargs will interpret arguments that same way.  Using null as a terminator helps ensure that even filenames with spaces and newlines will be interpreted correctly.

It's also possible to pipe results straight from `find` to `tar`:

```
$ find backup/ -type d | tar cf directory-structure.tar -T - --no-recursion
```

Invoking tar with *-T -* (or *--files-from -*) will cause it to read filenames from stdin, expecting each filename to be separated by a line break.

For maximum effect this can be combined with options for null-terminated strings:

```
$ find . -type d -print0 | tar cf directory-structure.tar --null --files-from - --no-recursion
```

Of these I consider this last version to be the most robust, because it supports both unusual filenames and (unlike xargs) is not inherently limited by system command-line sizes. (see `xargs --show-limits`)

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `find . -type d`; do mkdir -p /tmp/tar_root/`echo $i|sed 's/\.\///'`; done
pushd /tmp/tar_root
tar cf tarfile.tar *
popd
# rm -fr /tmp/tar_root
```

Answer (score 0):

go into the folder you want to start at (that's why we use find dot)
save tar file somewhere else. I think I got an error leaving it right there.
tar with r not c. I think with cf you keep creating new files and you only
get the last set of file subdirectories. tar r appends to the tar file.
--no-recursion because the find is giving you your whole list of files already
so you don't want to recurse.

find . -type d |xargs tar rf /somewhereelse/whatever-dirsonly.tar --no-recursion

tar tvf /somewhereelse/whatever-dirsonly.tar |more to check what you got.

Answer (score 0):

For AIX:

```
tar cvfD some-tarball.tar `find /dir_to_start_from -type d -print`
```