# use tree command output to create the same directory tree structure in different place

Tags: bash, unix, tree, tcsh

Is there command or UNIX utility that can take tree output like:

```
.
`-- First
    |-- data1
    |   `-- some_file -> /tmp/some_file
    `-- data2
```

and create the same tree structure in another place?

Comment: what about `cp`?

Comment: Using `tree` is an odd method... https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073992/2836621

Comment: @Nahuel : I don't want to use cp, I want to save tree output as kind of template and use it as fresh structure start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Tar only the Directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057925/tar-only-the-directory-structure?rq=1)

```
find First -type d -print0 | xargs -0 tar cf dir_template.tar --no-recursion
```

Where `First` is the top level directory that you want to save the structure of.

Copy `dir_template.tar` to your target destination, then:

```
tar xf dir_template.tar
```